# Log4J2 logging message: is there a limitation to its size?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I have noticed, that approximately 10Mb message that should have been logged using log4j2, was not in my logs.

I figured there might be a limitation on a single log4j2 message size. Does such limitation exist? If yes, how I could alter it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limitation to the size of messages logged with Log4j2.

You may have found a bug. Please raise this on the Log4j2 issue tracker, with steps for how to reproduce the issue. (Ideally a unit test that demonstrates the issue.)